# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error with MySQL variable in ZF1

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, fetchall

I have a MySQL query that works perfectly in PhpMyAdmin but throws an `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` when using within Zend Framework 1.12 and its `fetchAll()` method. Here it is:

```
SET @csum := 0;
SELECT s1.Date, (@csum := @csum + s1.total) as cumulative_sum
FROM (
        SELECT c.datefield AS Date, IFNULL(SUM(subscription_total),0) AS total
        FROM subscription s
        RIGHT JOIN calendar c
        ON c.datefield = DATE(subscription_date)
        WHERE (c.datefield BETWEEN
            (SELECT MIN(DATE(subscription_date)) FROM subscription)
            AND
            NOW()
        )
        GROUP BY DATE
    ) AS s1
```

The statement doesn't return any error if I remove the `SET` statement but I need to set a MySQL variable otherwise `cumulative_sum` will just be `NULL` values. Here is the code of the method:

```
public function findCumulativeCashflow($statut)
{
    $db = $this->_getDbTable();

    $dbAdapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($db->getAdapter()->getConfig());

    $sql = '<SQL statement above>';

    $statement = $dbAdapter->query($sql);

    $rows = $statement->fetchAll();

    return $rows; 
}
```

The error points the `$rows = $statement->fetchAll();` line, is there another ZF method to use with `SET @var := value`?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948782/mysql-query-with-mysql-variable-not-working-in-zend-framework-1), I need to use another query as fetchAll() cannot handle multiple queries.

I therefore need to set the MySQL variable with `$dbAdapter->query('SET @csum := 0;');` and then do the main query.