# Use mysql user variables in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, variables, zend-framework2

I want to run a mysql query including variables. A simple version of this looks like that:

```
$sql = "UPDATE mytable,
(SELECT @counter := IFNULL(@counter,0) + 1 as new_value,
        mycolumn
 FROM othertable
 ORDER BY mycolumn) i
SET mytable.counter_column = i.new_value
WHERE i.mycolumn = mytable.mycolumn";

$this
  ->getSlaveSql()
  ->getAdapter()
  ->getDriver()->getConnection()->execute($sql);
```

But the result value is always 1. If I run the query directly, I have a correct line of numbers. I think, the variables will be unset bei Zend, so that @counter is 0 on every row.

Comment: check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948782/mysql-query-with-mysql-variable-not-working-in-zend-framework-1

Comment: No, because it is already one query. I think I should use another method for that maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a stored procedure for this now.